# Use of operator()() without parentheses?

Tags: c++, templates

The following code is a dumbed down version of a wrapper around an object.  I would like to be able to access the underlying `Object` seamlessly, that is, without the need for parentheses, as the comments describe:

```
struct A
{
  void Func() {}
};

template <typename Object>
struct ObjectWrapper
{
  ObjectWrapper(Object& o) : object_(&o) {}

  operator Object& () { return *object_; }
  Object& operator ()() { return *object_; }

  Object* object_;
};


int main()
{
  A a;
  ObjectWrapper<A> obj(a);

  //
  // Trying to call Func() on the A object that 'obj' wraps...
  //

  obj.operator A& ().Func(); // Messy

  obj().Func(); // Better but still has parentheses

  // I really want to be able to say this:
  // obj.Func()
  // ...but cannot see how!
}
```

Can anyone please suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: Does `obj->Func()` count?

Comment: If `Func` is the only thing you want to access you could eliminate that and make it implicit. So `obj(arg1, arg2, ...)` would call `obj().Func(arg1, arg2,...)` like std::reference_wrapper` does.

Comment: In C++, accessing a wrapped object (such as in `std::unique_ptr`) is conventionally done using `operator->`.  `Object* operator->() { return object; };` then `obj->Func();`  as suggested by Goswin.  Note that `operator->` has some special behavior in C++, it is applied recursively until it reaches a plain pointer.

Comment: Not an expert. Can we use inheritance? `template<typename Object> struct ObjectWrapper: Object{...};`

Comment: There've been several proposals for being able to overload the direct member access operator `.` (though none are recent AFAIK). This would allow you to achieve exactly what you want (a "smart reference"). Time will tell if anything like this ever makes it into the language.
[P0060R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0060r0.html)
[P0352R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0352r0.pdf)
[P0416R1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0416r1.pdf)

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow, can you elaborate on "making it implicit" please with an example?

Comment: Like `operator Object& () { return object_->Func(); }`

Comment: @Goswin von Brederlow: oh I see now, thanks.  This does not work though since I won't just need to access `Func`, I'll need to access all the public members of whatever `Object` is...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need overload operator `->` and/or `*` (this is how smart pointers are done):

```cpp
template <typename Object>
struct ObjectWrapper {
    ObjectWrapper(Object& o)
        : object_(&o)
    {
        LOG();
    }

    Object* operator->() const
    {
        LOG();
        return object_;
    }

    Object& operator*() const
    {
        LOG();
        return *object_;
    }

    Object* object_;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    ObjectWrapper<A> obj { a };
    obj->Func();
    (*obj).Func();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ErEbxWE4P